# How can I append dynamic text contents to the end of existing text contents based on what WAS in it originally

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am currently making chrome extension, and would like to display additional content to the existing website.

Given following html

```
<p class="c1 c2">ID 1</p>
<p class="c1 c2">ID 2</p>
...
<p class="c1 c2">ID 20</p>
```

I would like to append modification to the ID # and append it to the end
So above example would be transformed to following

In following example result, I got the ID number and squared away the ID, then appended "SQ #" to the existing line.

```
<p class="c1 c2">ID 1 SQ 1</p>
<p class="c1 c2">ID 2 SQ 4</p>
...
<p class="c1 c2">ID 20 SQ 400</p>
```

How can I achieve this?

I tried to use the `$(".c1.c2").append`, but was not really successful.

I think I am both

1. not getting the existing ID correctly.
2. not getting the output properly formatted to be displayed (output shows up as `ID 1 funciton() {...}` instead of desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.text` method](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) can be used with a function argument, along with *its* arguments (the second of which is the old text content):

```js
$(".c1.c2").text((_index, oldValue) => oldValue
  .replace(/ID (\d+)/, (fullMatch, id) => `${fullMatch} SQ ${id ** 2}`));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="c1 c2">ID 1</p>
<p class="c1 c2">ID 2</p>
<p>…</p>
<p class="c1 c2">ID 19</p>
<p class="c1 c2">ID 20</p>
```

[`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) is also used with a function argument.
The regular expression `/ID (\d+)/` matches any `"ID "` followed by an arbitrary, non-negative integer.
The first argument, `fullMatch`, is reused, and `" SQ "` followed by the squared integer is appended using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

---

My take on a vanilla JS alternative:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".c1.c2")
  .forEach((elem) => elem.textContent = elem.textContent
    .replace(/ID (\d+)/, (fullMatch, id) => `${fullMatch} SQ ${id ** 2}`));
```

Comment: This achieved what I wanted. Thank you very much for the prompt reply.